# How to convert shape key animations from .glb to .usdz using the python usdz command line tools

Tags: python, animation, blender, gltf, usdz

I create models in blender and export them as .gltf files. I am experimenting with converting these models to .usdz files using the apple python command tools as discussed in [this video.](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/602/)

These conversions work well if the keyframed animation is made from either;

- armature animation (bones)
- simple position, rotation, scale

Keyframed animations made from shape keys are not carried over however. Is there something I need to do when I export the .glb file to ensure they will be part of the conversion to usdz?

Thanks for any advice.